# *** 'return' outside function (timer.py,line 7)

Tags: python

```
yes = set(['yes','y', 'ye', ''])
no = set(['no','n'])

choice = raw_input().lower()

if choice in yes:
    return True
if choice in no:
    return False
else:
    sys.stdout.write("Please respond with 'yes' or 'no'")
```

I thought it was my indents but I still cant get it to work, it's probably something so simple, I'm using this as a base for another file later so i need to check it works.

Comment: Is there a `def functionname():` line *at all* in your code?

Comment: The error is pretty clear... You're using `return` and you're not inside a function...

Answer (score 2):

You can only use a `return` statement in a function. Your code doesn't define a function *at all*.

Comment: After you fix this obvious error, there is a second error in your branching.  You need if-elif-else, not if-if-else.

Comment: @MelNicholson: No, not if this was a function and he could use `return`.. The `else:` branch is entirely optional, the `sys.stdout` line could be de-dented and the `else:` line removed.

Comment: I suppose it depends on how he fixes the first problem.  I was imagining he would store the status in a variable.  If he were using a function the return would do what he needs.

Comment: @MelNicholson: It is hard to figure out what this should return *to*. I suppose `sys.exit(0)` for yes, `sys.exit(1)` for no could do?

Comment: Agreed.  There is no context by which to determine what is right.  Given that the code is asking a question, I imagine he wants to feed that answer as a boolean to something else.